# Is it okay to use NPM packages along Composer in Laravel PHP project

Tags: npm, composer-php, laravel-5.5

Is it okay to install and use NPM for JS libraries along composer in *laravel* because *laravel* dependency already includes composer. Thanks.

Comment: Why should this be a problem?

Comment: I just need an advice because i'm new in laravel.

Comment: I assume you want to use the js library in the frontend? npm or yarn is the way to go for managing js libraries. Composer is intended only for php libraries. You could *in theory* manage the js libraries through composer yet I advise against that.

Comment: Furthermore, I recommend using one dependency manager as the main tool. In your setup this should be composer imo. Therefore, you could define  [scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-names), e.g. `post-install-cmd` in `composer.json` that then would run `npm install` automatically.

Comment: Okay, then the advise is: yes, that's okay.

Comment: Thanks for the advise guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is standard Laravel functionality.

NPM regulates the JS packages in the node_modules folder.
Both NPM and NODE.js need to be installed on your machine: https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

Composer regulates the PHP packages in the vendor folder.
This also needs to be installed separately on your machine: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2

Not sure what you mean by:

> ... because laravel dependency already includes composer.

Composer is needed anyway, no need to see it as a complication.